# pyplot save sequence of figs with avefig & clear?

Tags: python

I want to save a sequence of figures. E.g.,

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10.,5.))
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=1, nrows=2)
grid = [fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0]),fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 0])]
for i in 10:
    mu1 = <SOME IMAGE>
    mu2 = <SOME IMAGE>
    # First subplot
    ax = grid[0]
    ax.imshow(mu,cmap='copper')
    # Second subplot
    ax = grid[1]
    ax.imshow(mu2,cmap='copper')    
    ax.text(0.5, 1.15,f"Title for this fig {i}",fontsize=18, transform=ax.transAxes,ha='center')
    # save the figure
    f = open(f"frames/snap_t{i:04d}.png",'wb')
    plt.savefig(f)
    f.close()
    plt.close()
```

The problem is, if i don't clear the figure after each save, the plots get plotted on top of each other, so the title gets garbled and I think it uses a lot of memory. But if I close the figure, even after saving, then all but the first file contains an empty figure.
is there any ay i can save a figure in a file, then clear it without disturbing what I saved?
Thanks

I was hoping to have a sequence of plots saved. I have tried using just the filename in savefig(), and, as indicated, using a file descriptor so i can close the file before clearing the figure. But I still get nothing saved to all but the first file.